# whitespcace between wordpress tag name is not working for feed

Tags: php, wordpress

If I am using

http://example.net/?tag=tag1_without_whitepsace,tag2_without_whitespace&feed=rss2

then its working fine and providing me all the posts tagged with tag1_without_whitepsace and tag2_without_whitespace. On other side, if I am using

http://example.net/?tag=tag1 with whitepsace,tag2 with whitespace&feed=rss2

then I'm not getting any result in my feed though I tagged many post with tag1 with whitepsace and tag2 with whitepsace. I know in url whitespace is not allowed but I need to get correct feed result using such types of tags. please Anyone help me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add white space into a tag, category, or post title etc in the Dashboard, the system will convert it to `-` automatically for using it, i.e. if you type in `tag 1` it will be converted to `tag-1`, and `(with a space here)tag2(with another space here)` the spaces will be simply ignored.

You would never use spaces in the URL parameters, as well as for Feed, read more here http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds for displaying multiple tags.